# Angular httpClient order of server responses

Tags: angular, httpclient, subscribe

I am using the HTTPClient module that does the mapping automatically in a service.
That service use http.get to a remote API.
In subscribe to the service in a component that call that service several times inside a loop.

```
for (let i of this.symbols) {
    this.service.load(i).subscribe(response => {
      this.processsData(response);
    }, err => {
      console.log('Something went wrong ', err);
    })
```

Let say that in the loop i call the service for values:
A B C D
Most of the times i get the response in that order. But some times intead of A B C D y get A B D C or any different order.
How can i control return order from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rxjs' [concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html):

```
const httpObs = of(this.symbols)
  .pipe(
    map(i => i),
    concatMap(i => this.service.load(i))
  );
httpObs.subscribe(response => console.log(reseponse));
```